# C# HttpTriggered Azure funtion get content as interface from request

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am writing a simple http trigger azure function in c# as shown below.

```
[FunctionName("CommandReceiver")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequestMessage req,
    [ServiceBus("cqrs-commands", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "", EntityType = EntityType.Topic)]
    IAsyncCollector<BrokeredMessage> messageTopic,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    var request = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<IPayload>();

    var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(request );

    await messageTopic.AddAsync(brokeredMessage);

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(delRequest));
}
```

From the client i am using the below code:

```
async Task<bool> IBus.RaiseCommand(Payload message)
{
    var httpClient = HttpClientHelper.GetHttpClient(_azureSettings.Value.BaseUrl);
    var jsonInString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/CommandReceiver", 
                                    new StringContent(jsonInString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
}

public interface IPayload{

}

public class Payload : IPayload {

}
```

Using the above code i am not able to make it work. the azure function is throwing error at the line `req.Content.ReadAsAsync<IPayload>;`

Can anyone please help me the right way to achieve this?

Error i am getting is:

```
C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
Exception while executing function: CommandReceiver
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: CommandReceiver ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Could not create an instance of type Commands.Model.IPayload. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Action', line 2, position 10.
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: you cant deserialize using an interface because the serializer does not know which class implement your interface, have you tried `await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<Payload>();`

Comment: @Thomas I didnt tried. basically i am trying to have this function generic function. so it can be used for multiple things.

Comment: Yeah but you need to specify an implementation for your interface... otherwise it will never work, the error message is pretty explicit

Answer (score 0):

As @Thomas mentioned in the comment, serializer does not support `Deserialize` (and thus `ReadAsAsync`) calls with abstract types as generic parameter. Basically, just looking at JSON there's no way for serializer to know which concrete class it should instantiate to satisfy the desired interface requirement.

The obvious fix to this problem is to use `Payload` class directly:

```
await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<Payload>();
```

If you want to reuse the same Azure Function for multiple content types, you would need to either deserilize to `JObject` or `dynamic` and then act upon some properties, or add some sort of `if`-`else` logic based on HTTP request headers, route, etc.